# if ... in python statement failing

Tags: python, if-statement

My `if` statement is not working properly; when I call insert with the following parameters it doesn't work 100, 50, 20 or 10.

```
def insert():
    credit = input("Please insert pennies untill you have payed 80p: ")
    if False in [f == '100' or f == '50' or f == "20" or f == "10" for f in credit]:
        print("You can only use, 100p, 50p, 20p or 10p! Try again...")
        insert()

    global coin
    coin = (int(credit)) + coin
    print (coin)
    while coin < 80:
        insert()
    if coin >= 80:
        again = input("Would you like your change[c], or another item[b]?")
        if again == "c":
            print(coin-80)
        elif again == "b":
            program()

    return coin
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't loop over `credit`; `f` is being assigned *individual characters*. Since all your tests are for strings with 2 or more characters, you'll never find a match that way.

If your user has to enter *one* value, test against `credit` directly; use `not in` to test against multiple strings in one test:

```
if credit not in ('100', '50', '20', '10'):
```

You should not use recursion here; the recursive `input()` call will at some point return and resume the rest of your function. Use a `while` loop instead:

```
while True:
    credit = input("Please insert pennies untill you have payed 80p: ")
    if credit in ('100', '50', '20', '10'):
        break  # valid input
    print("You can only use, 100p, 50p, 20p or 10p! Try again...")
```